# Target class [redirect] does not exist lumen version 7

Tags: laravel, lumen

- Lumen Version: Lumen (7.2.2)
- Laravel Version: ^7.0
- PHP Version: 7.3.27

#### Description:

Having problem with error `Target class [redirect] does not exist.`

This line of code:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return redirect('/somewhere');
});
```

return error :

```
Target class [redirect] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [redirect] does not exist. at /var/www/apidev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811)
```

Comment: You can't install both laravel and lumen

Comment: actually not both, lumen is using laravel part @Nidecker

Comment: Lumen is using some parts from Laravel, yes, but everything is included in Lumen framework. `Target class [redirect] does not exist. at /var/www/apidev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illu...` that means you have laravel installed. Remove "laravel/framework" from your composer.json file (in the "require" block) and run `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

It might be some artifacts if you manage Lumen project for long time and did few major version updates for the framework.

In my case there was no any dependencies in the `composer.json` file, but inside vendor folder really there was Laravel framework files which created those conflitcs with helper functions.

`composer remove laravel/framework` in the project folder made
all necessary package updates and error is gone.